# LEDs and Arduino Microcontroller, How much Ampere, is it safe?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, power-supply, voltage, led

If I have 144 leds each requiring around 50-60mA, therefore I need 8amps right?
Where can I get a power supply that does not look like a rectangular rock but is also easy insertable into the typical European wall plug?

TL;DR: 5V and 8amps right?

Comment: It depends, put them all in series and you need 50-60 mA and more volts, put them in parallel and you need ~8.5 A and less volts. It's common to do a combination of the two.

Comment: You probably only have 25W of illumination and the rest is lossy from inefficient design

Answer (score 1):

Consumption:

```
144 Leds * 60 mA = 8,640 mA, running at 5 V
```

This is if you put them all parallel. Calculating the power:

```
P = V * I = 5 * 8,640 = 43 W)
```

By using a higher voltage (e.g. 24V):

```
P = V * I <=> 43 = 24 * I => I = 43 / 24 = 1.8 A
```

I'm sure you can get an adapter that can plug into a wall outlet for 2 A (or 3A or 4A if you want to be safe).

On internet there are plenty examples how to divide led strip(s).

(also I think 60 mA is quite a lot for a LED, I thought simple 3mm leds should be given max 40 mA, but maybe you have better ones).

Answer (score 0):

You could also multiplex your LEDs and light them a few at a time. At a not so high frequency the flickering will be hard to notice (maybe with rapid eye movement).

But then we have a lot more variables to consider... How many LEDs will you multiplex at a time? Does your arduino have enough pins to control them? ...